# Make visible what have changed after edit has been made

Tags: feature-request

Many times it happens that you are working on a question or answer and suddenly `An edit has been made to this post` appears. I personally press the button with stress because many times it happens that the edit is so minor that I can't see what actually changed and does it have any effect on the answer or not.

So I believe if SO had a content highlighting system that would show you what has been changed it would be great. For example the `Edit has been made` button shows and upon press changes would appear in some orange highlighting and disappear after a few moments.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view the revision history by clicking the edit timestamp near the bottom of the post:

[image]

I don't recall off the top of my head if getting that to show up requires a page refresh is the post hasn't been edited before or not.

Comment: This only happens if someone else edits the post. You just edited this very answer and I can't see what is changed!

Comment: @Emad Nah, it happens on all edits... except for the edits by the author within the first 5 minutes of a post (or until a comment is posted). (I removed the last sentence that said something like "I don't see us replacing content with a diff view" because I re-read your proposal and saw you were talking about a temporary display. Still don't see us doing it, to be honest, but still.)

Comment: Made a trivial edit just to showcase how it works. :)

Comment: Your trivial edit just helped prove how the last point works- I did not need to refresh to get the "edited" link- Just click the notice. :)

Comment: I see. But then I clicked on the link and it's gone. Thanks I haven't seen that! It's small though and navigates to a new page.